# "Article on" vs "article about"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is correct: *an excellent article on ant behaviour*  or *an excellent article about ant behaviour*?

If both are correct, is there a difference in their meaning and usage?

Comment: Related: ["Any news for" vs "any news on" vs "any news about"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32629/any-news-for-vs-any-news-on-vs-any-news-about), [When should I use "a discussion of" vs "a discussion on" vs "a discussion about"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16477/when-should-i-use-a-discussion-of-vs-a-discussion-on-vs-a-discussion-about)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both correct.

Difference in usage is very subtle.

*On* would be a preference in many contexts. *On* is probably more common in spoken and written language, but I believe *about* might be a little more common in spoken language than it might be in written language.