# This is a novel about (on?) integrity

Tags: prepositions

I feel comfortable saying "This is a novel *about* etiquette", but could I equally say "This is a novel *on* etiquette"?

If I had to say it, I would use "about" but I don't see anything wrong about using "on". I've been told, however, it would be wrong to use it here. Is it? Why? Don't we say "here  is a book on etiquette" or "a book on motorcycling"?

Comment: Sure, I think "on" is fine: just like your motorcycling example, "on" is simply an abbreviation or ellipsis of "*on the topic of". I'll be surprised but also interested if any of our other colleagues take the contrary position.

Comment: Ah! I had missed the key concept: *novel*! That changes things a bit. Of course, non-fiction works such as guides or handbooks can be *on a topic*, but novels rarely are. Novels *tell a story*, that is, they are usually *about* some people, their circumstances, and the vissictitudes of their lives. Of course the subtext or symbology may be a study of a particular topic, but it's harder to say the novel, as a book, is *on* a particular topic, per se. (Though you could say it's a *treatise on...* or somesuch where it draws the implications of some behavior or policy.)

Comment: a novel on, a novel about:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+novel+on%2Ca+novel+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20novel%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20novel%20about%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36368/article-on-vs-article-about

Comment: @DanBron Would you like to change your comment into an answer?

Comment: @DanBron I find your comment a perfect answer. Could you post it as such?  Thank you.

Comment: @Centarus The one about the character of novels? Sure. I'm enjoying the first rays of spring in NY right now, but I can convert it tonight.

Comment: @DanBron I appreciate that.

Comment: @Centaurus Sorry for the delay. Done now. Let me know if you want anything added to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concept here that's creating the dissonance is that you're talking about a *novel*.

Of course, a more general "book" can be *on* a topic, with textbooks being the canonical example: a textbook is the definitive work *on* a subject.

But novels are different. Novels tell a story: they're usually about some people, their circumstances, and the vissictitudes of their lives. *That is, novels are **narrative**, not **descriptive***.

Of course the subtext or symbology may be a study of a particular topic, which is why you could say a novel is *about* (in the sense of "circling around") some topic; for the same reason, you could also say "the work is *a treatise on* ...", or somesuch, where it draws the implications of some behavior or policy.

But it's harder to say the novel, as a book, is *on* a particular topic, per se.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that a piece of writing is 'on' something would generally mean the piece is using that thing as a subject.

In your example of 'a novel on etiquette', the novel would likely be about etiquette itself, such as a history of etiquette or a criticism of etiquette.

'A novel about etiquette' may be more likely to feature it as a theme, such as a fictional story about two groups of people, one group who follows the rules of etiquette and another who does not.